# Need to validate 2 files and write 3rd file

Tags: shell-script

File1 — Only Column1 Data Other columns are only Header,.

```
Column1, column55, column56, column57, column58, column59, column60,column61, column62
123
124
221
225
333
432
```

File2:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,…………column55, column59, column58, column54, column62, column61
xxx,123,yyy,zzz…….bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff,ggg,hhh,c:\a\b\c\ddd,ggg,hhh,c:\a\b\c\dsada,c:\a\b\c\kkja,c:\a\b\c\dsada,c:\a\b\c\kada
xxx,124,xxx,yyy………111,222,333,444,555,vvv,ddd,c:\a\b\c\uuu,ggg,hhh,c:\a\b\c\adada,c:\a\b\c\daa,c:\a\b\c\dsada,c:\a\b\c\kkjj
xxx,221,xxx,yyy………zzz,ddd,333,fff,ccc,ddd,333,c:\a\b\c\vvv,ggg,hhh,c:\a\b\c\dads,c:\a\b\c\adaa,c:\a\b\c\dsada,c:\a\b\c\kkjakjjsa
xxx,333,xxx,yyy………kkk,444,www,333,fff,223,323,c:\a\b\c\xxx,ggg,hhh,c:\a\b\c\dddjj,c:\a\b\c\adaad,c:\a\b\c\dsada,c:\a\b\c\kki2
xxx,787,xxx,yyy………zzz,ddd,333,fff,ccc,ddd,213,c:\a\b\c\yyy,ggg,hhh,c:\a\b\c\dddkf,c:\a\b\c\fasd,c:\a\b\c\dsada,c:\a\b\c\kku3
xxx,827,xxx,yyy………kkk,444,www,333,fff,sda,sda,c:\a\b\c\zzz,ggg,hhh,c:\a\b\c\ddyu,c:\a\b\c\fsssfs,c:\a\b\c\dsada,c:\a\b\c\k233
```

The validation workflow is:

- If file1’s column1 = file2’s column2 then. — comparing header and data
  And (file1.column55 = file2.column55. — Comparing only header if same 
    OR file1.column56 = file2.column56 — Comparing only header if same 
    OR file1.column57 = file2.column57 )— Comparing only header if same 
  THEN Write  in file3.csv from file1

The desired output should be: (similar to file1 format but data supposed to be)

```
Column1 Column55 column57, column58  column59  column60 column61, column62
```

Comment: Excellent. above i have given the example files only but the actual file2,csv is having the 230+ columns and the file2,csv is having multiple paths by giving the 4 slashes it may read wrong column also. I have to capture the 55th column (c:\a\b\c\ddd).

Comment: Wherein lies the validation? Also, please format your post using the formatting tool provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
awk -F ',' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $2 in a{print $2", "$8}' file1 file2 | sed 's/,.*\\/, /g'

123, ddd
124, uuu
221, vvv
333, xxx
```

- `-F '[\\\\,]'` we require two delimiters as per your expected Output(comma and backslash). to escape the backslash behavior we required 4 backslashes.

Comment: Excellent. above i have given the example files only but the actual file2,csv is having the 230+ columns and the file2,csv is having multiple paths by giving the 4 slashes it may read wrong column also. I have to capture the 55th column (c:\a\b\c\ddd).

Comment: @Krishna try the updated answer... use your desired field($55) instead if $8

Comment: Thank you so much,. I am closer to solution but my bad the file  File2 is having multiple paths and i need to extract the 55th column from the file. the main issue here is File2.csv is having 230+ columns and having multiple paths like (c:\a\b\c\ddd)

Comment: Can you please check the requirement which i posted on the top. It was the exact requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
awk -F ',' '
FNR == NR   {T[$1]
             next
            }
$2 in T     {n = split ($8, X, /\\/)
             print $2, X[n]
            }
' OFS=, file1 file2 
123,ddd
124,uuu
221,vvv
333,xxx
```

Adapt field numbers to taste (e.g. `$8` --> `$55`). If that doesn't satisfy your request, narrow down / improve your specification & sample data.